# Child VF Page that create multiple grand childen does not create the records correctly

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience

I am using a package from Michael Welburn [GitHub](https://github.com/mwelburn/Visualforce-Edit-Multiple-Records)
to create multiple records for my Custom Object (FFDriver__c). 
One precision, I am working in Lightning.

My configuration:

3 Objects - All with Master-Detail relationship.:

- Opportunity (parent)
- Fact_Finder__c (child)
- FFDriver__c (grandchild).

On my Opportunity detail page I have a Lightning Component with several buttons which open VF Pages (Fact_Finder__c) with different record types.

My problem is when I save the DriverForm (doSave) the records are created (Fact Finder with all infos and Driver with only the one in  initChildRecord) but nothing that I put in other fields.
[image: VF Page DriverForm]

I have tried to simplify the code (taking out styles and many fields). Sorry it is still very long and the formatting terrible….

**VF PAGE (DriverForm) – grandchild level**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Fact_Finder__c" extensions="EditableDriverListExtension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
        <apex:form style="width:800px; text-align:center; margin:auto;" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageMessages id="messages"/>
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!doSave}" value="Save" immediate="true" styleclass="buttonsubmit" />
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!doCancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" styleClass="buttoncancel" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="black" layout="block">
                    <apex:pageblocksection title=" Driver Details" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="2">
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!FF.Name}"/>
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!FF.Opportunity_Name__r.Name}"/>
                        <apex:pageblocksection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="black" layout="block" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
                    <apex:pageblocksection showheader="false" collapsible="true" id="childList" columns="1" >
                        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!ZERO}" />
                        <apex:outputLabel value="No Drivers currently register. Click below to Add one." rendered="{!NOT(hasChildren)}"/>
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!children}" var="driv" rendered="{!hasChildren}" columnsWidth="5%,10%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%,5%,10%,5%,5%,5%,10%" >
                            <apex:column headerValue=" ">
                                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}" />
                                <apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!removeFromList}" rerender="childList, messages" immediate="true">
                                    <apex:param name="removeIndex" assignTo="{!removeIndex}" value="{!rowNum}" />
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Driver Name" >
                                <apex:inputField value="{!driv.Driver_Name__c}" style="width: 120px; height: 20px"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headerValue="DOB" >
                                <apex:inputField value="{!driv.Date_of_Birth__c}" style="width: 80px; height: 20px"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Gender" >
                                <apex:inputField value="{!driv.Gender__c}" style="width: 80px; height: 20px"/>
                            </apex:column>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Add Driver" action="{!addToList}" rerender="childList, messages" immediate="true" styleclass="buttonadd" />
                    </apex:pageblocksection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

**Extension (EditableDriverListExtension)**

```
public with sharing class EditableDriverListExtension extends EditableList{
        public Fact_Finder__c FF {get; private set;}
        string FFId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('FFId');
        public EditableDriverListExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
            super(stdController);
            this.FF = [SELECT Id, Name, Opportunity_Name__r.Name FROM Fact_Finder__c WHERE Id =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('FFId')];
            this.childList = [SELECT Id,
                    Motor_Fact_Finder_No__c,
                    Driver_Name__c,
                    Date_of_Birth__c,
                    Gender__c,
                    Class_of_License__c,
                    Licence_Number__c....
            FROM FFDriver__c
            WHERE Motor_Fact_Finder_No__c=: mysObject.Id];
        }
        public List<FFDriver__c> getChildren(){
            return (List<FFDriver__c>)childList;
        }
        public override sObject initChildRecord(){
            FFDriver__c child = new FFDriver__c();
            child.Motor_Fact_Finder_No__c = FF.Id;
            child.Opportunity_Name__c = FF.Opportunity_Name__r.Name;
            child.Accidents__c= 'No';
            child.Claims_last_5_years__c= 'No';
            child.Convictions__c= 'No';
            child.Licence_Suspended_or_Cancelled__c= 'No';
            child.Claims_Bonus__c= 'No';
            child.Restricted_Nominated_Driver_Policy__c= 'No';
            child.Is_the_driver_less_than_25__c= 'No';
            return child;
        }
        public PageReference doCancel(){
            return new PageReference('/' +FF.Opportunity_Name__r.Id);
        }
        public PageReference doSave(){
            System.debug(childList);
            try{
                upsert childList;
                pageReference pageRef = new PageReference ('/'+FF.Opportunity_Name__r.Id);
                pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                return pageRef;
            }catch(DMLException saveEx){
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Extend (EditableList)**

```
public abstract with sharing class EditableList {
    public final Integer ZERO { get; private set; }
    public sObject mysObject { get; protected set; }
    public List<sObject> childList { get; set; }
    public String removeIndex { get; set; }
    @TestVisible protected List<sObject> removeChildList { get; set; }

    public EditableList() {
        this.ZERO = 0;
        this.removeChildList = new List<sObject>();
        this.childList = new List<sObject>();
    }
    public EditableList(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this();
        this.mysObject = (sObject) stdController.getRecord();
    }
    public Boolean getHasChildren() {
        return !childList.isEmpty();
    }
    public virtual sObject initChildRecord() {
        return new FFDriver__c();
    }
    public void addToList() {
        childList.add(initChildRecord());
    }
    public void removeFromList() {
        try {
            Integer rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(removeIndex) - 1;
            if (childList.size() > rowIndex && rowIndex >= 0) {
                sObject sobj = childList.remove(rowIndex);
                if (sobj.Id != null) {
                    removeChildList.add(sobj);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        try {
            List<sObject> insertChildList = new List<sObject>();
            List<sObject> updateChildList = new List<sObject>();
            for (sObject sobj : childList) {
                if (sobj.Id == null) {
                    insertChildList.add(sobj);
                }
                else {
                    updateChildList.add(sobj);
                }
            }
            insert insertChildList;
            update updateChildList;
            delete removeChildList;
            return new PageReference('/' + mysObject.Id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Database.rollback(sp);
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

debug log:

```
'16:09:16:041 USER_DEBUG [51]|DEBUG|(FFDriver__c:{Motor_Fact_Finder_No__c=a0OO0000007hDOhMAM, Opportunity_Name__c=test motor - driver, Accidents__c=No, Claims_last_5_years__c=No, Convictions__c=No, Licence_Suspended_or_Cancelled__c=No, Claims_Bonus__c=No, Restricted_Nominated_Driver_Policy__c=No, Is_the_driver_less_than_25__c=No}, FFDriver__c:{Motor_Fact_Finder_No__c=a0OO0000007hDOhMAM, Opportunity_Name__c=test motor - driver, Accidents__c=No, Claims_last_5_years__c=No, Convictions__c=No, Licence_Suspended_or_Cancelled__c=No, Claims_Bonus__c=No, Restricted_Nominated_Driver_Policy__c=No, Is_the_driver_less_than_25__c=No})'
```

Thank you in advance for your help. 
Sylvie.

Comment: Sylvie, I tried the similar code in my org and works in both classic and lightning environment. So the issue should be somewhere else. My suggestions are: 1. add a System.debug for ChildList value before do upsert in doSave() function. See whether the values are correct and whether you can manually upsert those values 2. Add a apex:pageMessages section to find out the error messages.

Comment: Hi @LanceShi, sorry for the late reply, I was away last week. All the values that are hardcoded in the initChildRecord are upserted correctly but none that I entered manually. It is also what the debug log tells me.

Comment: So you are saying that before the line: `upsert childList` in your controller, you debugged childList and it was not the correct value? I tried with similar code in my org but didn't repro for me. I wouldn't say it is lightning issue. And plus, I really don't see a reason you need to use a framework here.

Comment: It upsert only the value that are hardcoded in the initChildRecord but not the other ones such as driver name, DOB, gender that I entered manually in my form (see image above). What do you recommend? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have added a `System.debug(childList)` line before the line: `upsert childList`? What is the output? Before you click the save button, click Add Driver button for several times and then click save. What will happen in the debug log?

Comment: I have updated my extension above with the line where I put the System.debug and added the result of the debug log after trying to create 2 drivers.

Comment: I still can't reproduce your error. Sorry. Everything just runs fine in my own org with similar code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the attribute immediate=true in the VF page in the save button. 
By removing it, the getters/setters are fire correctly and the input values are captured and saved as requested.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSave}" value="Save" styleclass="buttonsubmit" />
```